# Getting an error in info path form in SharePoint when i click on submit or save button

Tags: 2013, infopath, infopath-rules

When I click on submit button InfoPath form I am getting following error:

> The form cannot be submitted because it contains validation errors.
>   Errors are marked with either a red asterisk (required fields) or a
>   red, dashed border (invalid values). Field or group:
>   my:_x0633__x0628__x062f__x0020__x06 Error: can not be blank.

What should I do to clear this error?

Comment: Do you have any datetime field on your form?

Answer (score 1):

- Open the list in InfoPath via `list tab > customize form`
- It will open up newform.aspx in InfoPath
- Once it is open check mandatory fields available in that form.
- Make sure all mandatory fields are available and deployed in newform.aspx
- Or
- If you don’t want them to be displayed in newform.aspx just remove mandatory option
- Republish the form and check behavior.

Comment: Did you tried above mentioned steps? are they working for you?